# How to configure Rails with Puma to use SSL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, puma

I only found how to [start puma using SSL](https://github.com/puma/puma):

`$ puma -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:9292?key=path_to_key&cert=path_to_cert'`

However, there is no description about how to include an intermediate CA cert in the documentation. Could someone point me in the right direction? I am using Puma `1.6.3`

Thanks!

Comment: @Smartis Thanks for the edit! I am considering to close and/or even delete this question because it is a bit… Redundant and oddly specific? Thoughts?

Comment: Remember to also enable `force_ssl` and ACME challenges in Rails.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Combining certificate and bundle will work only if you use nginx.

Without nginx, you can use `ca` and `verify_mode` options:

```
rails s puma -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:9292?key=path_to_key.key&cert=path_to_cert.crt&verify_mode=none&ca=path_to_root_bundle.crt'
```

Source: https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/lib/puma/binder.rb

Comment: Path to root bundle? What the heck is that?

Comment: Yeah, what's root bundle? Do you mean the fullchain certificate?

Comment: I love u. I couldn't find any way and this magic parameter just saved my day.

Answer (score 9):

Kinda late to the party but, I have another solution, you can see [my post](https://medium.com/@matayoshi.mariano/how-to-add-ssl-to-your-localhost-with-puma-37a66a649f29) for more details.

First create the certificate for your localhost using [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert)

```
mkcert localhost
```

If you want to have another domain to work on HTTPS, just replace localhost to the one you want, like `mkcert mylocalhost-with-a-cool-domain.com`

After this, I created a `local-certs` folder under the `config` folder and pasted the cert and key there.

Now you should mark these cert as trusted, I’m working on a Mac computer, so not sure how to handle this particular part on Windows or on a Linux distro. Check out the post, it has screenshoots. In resume, you will need to drag the certificate created with `mkcert` to the Keychain Access.

Then in your puma config file, create one if you don't have it and name it `puma.rb`, you should have something like

```rb
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['THREAD_COUNT'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        3001
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'production'

if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'development'

  # If you didn't place the cert and key under `local-certs` you should change this
  localhost_key = "#{File.join('config', 'local-certs', 'localhost-key.pem')}" 
  localhost_crt = "#{File.join('config', 'local-certs', 'localhost.pem')}"

  ssl_bind '0.0.0.0', 3000, {
    key: localhost_key,
    cert: localhost_crt,
    verify_mode: 'none'
  }
end
```

Then running `bundle exec puma -C puma.rb` or `bundle exec rails s` should do it :D

If anyone has a question, pls let me know. Hope it helps future readers!

Comment: Can we set it up for any domain? rather than a specific one?

Comment: @pjo336 yep, just replace `localhost` to whatever you prefer. In my job, we have a couple of services like: `api.myjob.com`, `client.myjob.com`, `another_name.myjob.com`. If that's your case, you can just go and do `mkcert *.myjob.com` and use that certificate

Comment: @MatayoshiMariano using the wildcard will work for any subdomain on myjob.com, but not for the root domain at the same time. I have not yet figured out how to solve this with mkcert in setup with puma.

Comment: .. using the wildcard will work for any subdomain on myjob.com, but not for the root domain at the same time. For this, run `mkcert "*.myjob.com myjob.com`. Note the quotes around the wildcard version. --ment to update my comment, can't after 5min -.-

Comment: @swiknaba i didn't test it for the root domain, will have to check that and get back to you

Comment: For Rails 6.x you should use `if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'development'`

Answer (score 4):

`rails s puma -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:9292?key=certkey.key&cert=cert.crt&verify_mode=peer&ca=root_bundle.crt`

Just make sure you set the `verify_mode=peer`.

Answer (score 3):

while we are using combo Nginx+PhusionPassenger as well. You cant specify Chain cert file in nginx either. The trick is to bundle all certs within one certificate and then set the new certificate file as a certificate in your server configuration. You will find more information in [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html). Check SLL Certificate Chains section.

```
cat www.example.com.crt bundle.crt > www.example.com.chained.crt
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Appending the intermediate certificates does not seem to work in Puma.

Answer (score 0):

code here: https://gist.github.com/ouaziz/cef138ca35d13d70a5d4971077fb0703

create file ssl.sh with ======>

```
#!/bin/sh

# See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self for overview

ssl_dir='ssllocal'
mkdir -p $ssl_dir
openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:x -out $ssl_dir/server.pass.key 2048

# be sure to use *.lvh.me as the common name, allows us to hit admin.lvh.me, etc.
openssl rsa -passin pass:x -in $ssl_dir/server.pass.key -out $ssl_dir/server.key

rm $ssl_dir/server.pass.key
openssl req -new -key $ssl_dir/server.key -out $ssl_dir/server.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in $ssl_dir/server.csr -signkey $ssl_dir/server.key -out $ssl_dir/server.crt

#==== end of file
```

## doc

## to run rails with this ssl

```
# mkdir ssllocal
# chmod a+x ssl.sh
# ./ssl.sh
```

## # run

```
# rails s -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:3000?key=ssllocal/server.key&cert=ssllocal/server.crt&verify_mode=none&ca=ssllocal/server.crt'
```

## # or

```
# ./bin/ssl
```

## create file ssl in bn with ======>

```
# bin/ssl
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if ! gem list foreman -i --silent; then
  echo "Installing foreman..."
  gem install foreman
fi

exec foreman start -f Procfilessl.dev "$@"
#==== end of file
```

Answer (score -8):

It may be a better idea to use [Phusion Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) + Nginx for SSL support. This combo has widely available documentation and is very easy to setup because it's currently the most popular app server choice, and used by the likes of New York Times, Symantec, AirBnB, etc. Here's how you do it if you have Nginx with Phusion Passenger installed:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name yourapp.local;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate ...;
    ssl_key ...;
    root /path-to-your-app/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

Comment: DV for not answering the question.

Comment: It may not be the answer you're looking for, but it is a valid answer. If something doesn't work then it may be better to look at alternatives instead.

Comment: The question is "How to configure Rails with Puma to use SSL?". I don't see how explaining a Phusion Passenger setup even remotely answers that. I assume OP is aware of the various server choices and chose Puma for whatever reason, as I was when I found this question. There have been good things said about Puma, and I specifically wanted to get it working so I could test it.  So no, you telling me to go use something else isn't helpful at all.