# Rails SSL while running only Puma on EC2 AWS instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

*Specs: Rails 4.2.4, Ruby 2.1.9, running puma, EC2 instance in production mode*

I have an SSL certificate that I want to install on my server but using techniques like this one yields no results

```
rails s puma -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:9292?key=path_to_key.key&cert=path_to_cert.crt&verify_mode=none&ca=path_to_root_bundle.crt'
```

[How to configure Rails with Puma to use SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063117/how-to-configure-rails-with-puma-to-use-ssl)

also

```
RAILS_ENV=production rvmsudo -E rails s puma -b "ssl://0.0.0.0:9292?key=${KEY_PATH}&cert=${CERT_PATH}&verify_mode=peer&ca=${CERT_BUNDLE_PATH}" -p 80
```

Instead of a functioning server I get

> Puma starting in single mode...
>   * Version 3.2.0 (ruby 2.1.9-p490), codename: Spring Is A Heliocentric Viewpoint
>   * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
>   * Environment: production
>   * Listening on tcp://ssl://0.0.0.0:9292?key=~/evslideshow.key&cert=~/e3b162f57ea48f91.crt&verify_mode=peer&ca=~/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt:80
>   Exiting
>   **> /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9@slideshow/gems/puma-3.2.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:240:in
>   `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)**

Now my mind is playing with different options.  Am I just missing some fundamental aspect of using puma here?  The puma documentation is very scared which is why I'm asking here.  Or I could use Nginx because it seems like there is alot of documentation on the internets on setting that up with SSL certificate.

If there is a simpler fix for puma then I will just use that.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution by reading through some of the [issue pages](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/512#issuecomment-48829088) on puma's Github page.  Apparently we must call puma directly, and not through `rails server`, despite what was said here in this [old stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063117/how-to-configure-rails-with-puma-to-use-ssl)

The working code is

```
RAILS_ENV=production rvmsudo -E puma -d -b "ssl://0.0.0.0:443?key=${KEY_PATH}&       
cert=${CERT_PATH}&verify_mode=peer&ca=${CERT_BUNDLE_PATH}" -p 80
```

Make sure to turn on config.force_ssl in your production config file as well.