# SSL with Puma, HTTP parse error, malformed request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

Attempting to configure Puma with HTTPS for a rails application being served in a private network on a remote server.  [Puma Docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/puma#Binding_TCP___Sockets) make it look like it is possible, and they provide this command:

```
puma -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:9292?key=path_to_key&cert=path_to_cert'
```

Steps taken (for testing purposes):

**Generate private key and self-signed certificate**

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/puma_test.key -out /etc/zzz_puma_test.crt
```

**Boot up Puma**

```
rvmsudo rails s -p 443 -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1?key=/etc/puma_test.key&cert=/etc/zzz_puma_test.crt'
```

When I boot up the server, in the logs I see this which I think is odd: `Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:443`  It is like Puma is still booting up in http as opposed to https.  Here is terminal logs in its entirety when booting up puma:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.8 application starting in development on http://ssl://127.0.0.1?key=/etc/puma_test.key&cert=/etc/zzz_puma_test.crt:443
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:443
```

When I attempt to access the site, I get this error in terminal:

> HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.

In the firefox browser itself, it provides this feedback:

> SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

What is odd is that I do the exact steps above locally on my computer, for an app being served locally on my computer, and it all works fine.

- I created a new app
- Ran the above line to generate the secret key and the self-signed certificate
- Ran the above line to boot up the server
- In terminal when the server is booted up, it shows it is listening properly (in other words: never mentions http): `Listening on ssl://127.0.0.1:443?key...cert...`
- Connecting to `https://localhost/blogs` works just fine.

Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that I am using linux machine as opposed to my mac?  Or, perhaps it is that my testing app lives on a remote server in my network? I looked at the method that generates this error.  It is [parse_error, line 95 of events.rb](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/lib/puma/events.rb).

Resources already looked at:

- [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063117/how-to-configure-rails-with-puma-to-use-ssl)
- [GithubGist](https://gist.github.com/tadast/9932075)
- [Open Issue](https://github.com/gbarillot/rails-vue-demo-app/issues/12), [closed issue](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/986),

I have tried tweaking the `rails s` command above with a number of different small changes:

- changed IP from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`
- do not specify the `-p 443` option
- specify the actual, internal IP address instead of `127.0.0.1` (this is being served on an internal network)

I have also tried deleting my browsing history, and tried accessing the site from multiple browsers.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is your operation system?

Comment: And please would you share your puma configuration file?

Comment: @zeitnot It is Ubuntu 16.04.  And there are no puma configuration file.  It is using all the puma defaults.

Comment: Did you try these instructions https://gist.github.com/tadast/9932075#gistcomment-2004730

Comment: @zeitnot I can certainly try experimenting some more.

Comment: Are you able to run the same command with the development environment? It will probably give you a more verbose error if you try running the same in development mode instead, and that can help you hunt down the problem. What do your logs say?

Comment: Have you tried launching puma directly instead of through rails s?
It seems the behavior can be different between the two https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1253

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Followed all the provided steps with just generated new Rails application (Rails 5.2, Ruby 2.6.1, MacOS). All works well

Comment: @Glyoko I attempted booting in development mode.  One weird thing I notice is that it appears it continues to do http as opposed to https:  `Rails 4.2.8 application starting in development on http://ssl:...`

Comment: I assume the specified key  and cert paths should be absolute paths to the key and cert files from the file system?  I assume that when I do `/this/path` it is not doing it relatively from the application but instead from the file system?

Comment: What Ruby and Puma versions?

Comment: @mwp Ruby 2.3.3p222, Puma 3.12.0

Comment: Missing steps for repro: 1. add `gem 'puma'` to Gemfile, 2. append `, '~> 1.3.13'` to `gem 'sqlite3'` in Gemfile, 3. run `bundle` after these changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is the solution that finally worked for me:**

First I had to create a puma config file with the `ssl_bind` directive:

```
# /<path_to_app>/puma/development.rb
ssl_bind '127.0.0.1', '9292', {
   cert: ‘/etc/puma_test.key',
   key: ‘/etc/zzz_puma_test.crt'
}
```

Then I had to boot up the server with `puma` as opposed to `rails s`.  For whatever reason, I just could not get `rails s` to work. In the command to boot up puma, I had to make sure to specify `-C` and the path to the puma config file:

```
rvmsudo puma -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:443?key=/etc/puma_test.key&cert=/etc/zzz_puma_test.crt' -C /<path_to_app>/puma/development.rb
```

Comment: Just put the correct address and port number in your `ssl_bind` directive and you can omit the `-b` command-line argument altogether.

Answer (score 2):

I built a fresh VM with Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS server (HWE kernel), installed RVM, Ruby 2.3.3, and Rails 4.2.8, followed your repro instructions, and... it works great. I used 0.0.0.0 as the listening address and accessed the guest's address from the host machine.

Guest:

```
mwp@ubuntu:~/Code/blag$ export rvmsudo_secure_path=1
mwp@ubuntu:~/Code/blag$ rvmsudo rails s -p 443 -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0?key=/etc/puma_test.key&cert=/etc/zzz_puma_test.crt'
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.8 application starting in development on http://ssl://0.0.0.0?key=/etc/puma_test.key&cert=/etc/zzz_puma_test.crt:443
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on ssl://0.0.0.0:443?key=/etc/puma_test.key&cert=/etc/zzz_puma_test.crt
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

Host:

```
mwp@macos:~$ curl -Ik https://192.168.10.137
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
ETag: W/"b56dd5f9363ed0f7bd4d11c36d9471dd"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: 555223a6-3f70-49cf-8b30-92d3047ff8a6
X-Runtime: 0.009792
```

Guest:

```
Started HEAD "/" for 192.168.10.112 at 2019-02-28 15:39:19 -0600
Cannot render console from 192.168.10.112! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by Rails::WelcomeController#index as */*
  Rendered /home/mwp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-4.2.8/lib/rails/templates/rails/welcome/index.html.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

So clearly something else is missing here: some configuration on your server, some Gem in your Gemfile, or some configuration in your Rails project.

Comment: You clearly put work into this, so I really appreciate it.  I'll keep exploring.

Comment: @Neil You're welcome. I was disappointed when I didn't get the error! If you have any updates just ping me here and I'll take another look.

Comment: One major thing I notice is that when you booted up your server, it says: `Listening on ssl://0.0.0.0:443?key...cert...`.  On mine it says: `Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:443`.  So the issue seems to be that it is refusing to boot up appropriately.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Neil That's not what you wrote in your question above. Did something change?

Comment: I will update my post to show entirely what the server says when I boot it up

Comment: @Neil It looks like you've got a space or a tab in between the `?` and the `key=`, so yeah, that's not right. It's serving up the site over plain http (or raw tcp?) now.

Comment: @Neil Now you're missing the `?`. You've definitely got some funny terminal business going on, possibly a bad copy/paste resulting in hidden control characters?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189237/discussion-between-mwp-and-neil).